# R Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I am learning django framework and i am getting an error "
Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name."
I am including my code here.

### `results.py`:

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block main_content %}

<h1>{{question.question_text}}</h1>

<ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <li>{{choice.choice_text}} -- {{choice.votes}} vote{{choice.votes|pluralize}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:details' question.id }">Vote again</a>
{% endblock%}
```

This is urls.py file of polls app.

### `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^$",views.index,name="index"),  #127.0.0.1:8000/polls
    url(r"^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$",views.details,name="details"),
    url(r"^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$",views.results,name="result"),
    url(r"^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$",views.vote,name="vote"),
]
```

### `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
# from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Question
from django.urls import reverse


def results(request,question_id):
    question=get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    return render(request,"polls/results.html",{"question":question})

def vote(request,question_id):
    question=get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice=question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except:
        return render(request,"polls/details.html",{'question':question,"error_message":"Please select a choice"})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes+=1
        selected_choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("polls:results",args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: Post your urls.py

Comment: Can we see the urls.py for polls?

Comment: You have a problem in your `urls.py` file, hence everyone asking to see it.

Comment: @Reez0   i have provided the required code,please check it out.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser i have provided the rerquired code,please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("polls:results",args=(question.id,)))
```

To

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("polls:result",args=(question.id,)))
```

Since it's defined in your urls.py as

```
url(r"^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$",views.results,name="result"),
```

Comment: I did what you told to do but still same error is there.